# In A trapezium ABCD, AB= 7cm, CD = 16cm, BE || AD is drawn. P,Q,R,S are mid point

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]
I got of area of BEC = 144 after this i calculated height and
I got area of traingle ABD =126.

In question options given are (a) 208 (b) 56 (c) 28 (d) 112
Is my answer right or wrong?

Comment: Could you rotate the picture or, better yet, transcribe it into $\LaTeX$?

Comment: I'm doing it through mobile. I can rotate the image

Comment: That's nice to know.  Please rotate the image then so we can read it better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that :

Area ($\bigtriangleup$ EBC) = $2$ Area ($\bigtriangleup$ EPC) = $4$ Area ($\bigtriangleup$ EQC) = $8$ Area ($\bigtriangleup$ EQR) = $16$ Area ($\bigtriangleup$ ESR) = $16 \cdot9$ = $144$ cm$^{2}$

Now,  let the height of the trapezium be $x$ cm.
Calculating the area of trapezium ABCD by two methods, we have:

$7x+144 = \frac {1}{2}\cdot (7+16)\cdot x$

which gives $x= 32$$ cm.

Now, ABDE is a parallelogram with a side of $7$ cm and height $32$ cm.

Hence, the area of  $\bigtriangleup$ ABD $ =\frac {1}{2}\cdot7\cdot32 = 112$ cm$^{2}.$